# Angular shared module exports component imported by another module

Tags: angular, typescript, shared-module

I have 3 modules. Lets call them `StoreModule`, `BookModule`, `PaperModule`. Store sells books, so store uses book. Book consist of paper, so uses paper, the exact same paper as store uses. And store uses paper as well. Here comes the problem! Now the real life example for this in angular:

**paper.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { PaperComponent } from './paper.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    PaperComponent
  ],
  exports: [
    PaperComponent
  ]
})
export class PapaerModule { }
```

So far so good, no angular errors.

**book.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BookComponent } from './book.component';
import { PaperModule } from './paper.module'

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    BookComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    PaperModule
  ],
  exports: [
    BookComponent
  ]
})
export class BookModule { }
```

Here, `book.component.html` looks like this:

```
<app-paper></app-paper>
```

Everything is still fine, no errors. But when we want to use both (not sure we will need both, maybe we will only need paper, maybe book too):

**store.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BookModule } from './book.module'
import { PaperModule } from './paper.module'

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BookModule,
    PaperModule
  ]
})
export class StoreModule { }
```

Here's the error I get:

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Type PaperComponent is part of the declarations of 2 modules: BookModule and StoreModule! Please consider moving PaperComponent to a higher module that imports BookModule and StoreModule. You can also create a new NgModule that exports and includes PaperComponent then import that NgModule in BookModule and StoreModule.

How could I structure this all the way, in order to export both component (BookComponent and PaperComponent) so I could use them in other module? I wanna make PaperComponent reusable by BookModule and Storemodule too. For some module I only need paper, but for some other I need book which includes paper as well. I hope you can understand my problem!

Comment: What you are doing is 100% correct, can you serach for `PaperComponent` in whole project, may be you left it in app.module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just ran your setup through [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hns1uu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fbook.component.ts) and it is without problem.

Check your code to make sure that `BookModule` does not declare `PaperComponent`.

**book.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BookComponent } from './book.component';
import { PaperModule } from './paper.module';
import { PaperComponent } from './paper.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    BookComponent,
    // This would be a problem
    PaperComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    PaperModule
  ],
  exports: [
    BookComponent,
  ]
})
export class BookModule { }
```

Comment: Can't understand why, but when I recreated all the code, it started working, even though I  used the exact same code I included with my question. Anyway, thanks for your help and  your highlight!